# If I'm deploying a Django website with Nginx, do I need a service such as Digital Ocean on top of that?

Tags: python, django, webserver, web-deployment

I want to launch a website I've written in Python/Django. I want to host it on an Nginx Web Server. However I'm not sure if I need a service such as Digital Ocean or Heroku. What benefits do these services provide that I can't get with only Nginx?

Comment: Strange question. Digital Ocean is (one of the places) where you *put* your nginx server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run website you need to own machine with static ip address. It can be your own machine or you need remote machine provided by [DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/f11d3b445927), Heroku, AWS or other similar service.

Then you need to run nginx on this machine. But nginx only acts as proxy and it is not enough to run Django application. You need some wsgi server behind nginx, for example [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).

Take a look at this [article](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-django-app-with-nginx-gunicorn-postgresql-supervisor-9c6d556a25ac) to understand more.